# All list item popovers for new items showing at once on hover- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a categorised list of items from a SQL Server database on my page. I also have stars next to the newer items to draw user attention. My code should hopefully display popovers for each of the new items when the user hovers over each of them. My problem is that no matter what new item/star I hover on, they all appear at once. Ive tried using a for loop for each item and giving each `<li>` a unique class or id in different attempts. This is part of the code looping through the Db and also displaying the "new"

```
<li>
    <?php 
        if(strtotime($itemDetails['posted']) > (strtotime('-30 days'))){
            echo '<i class="icon-star" data-content="This item is new on Corkboard. Check it out!" data-original-title="New Item"></i>';}
            echo '<a href="newGenView.php?id='.$itemid.'">'.$itemDetails['name'].' - '.$itemDetails['description'].'</a>';
    ?>
</li>
<?php
    }//foreach
    echo '</ul>';
    }//foreach
?>
```

This is the code instantiating the popover.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.icon-star').popover(options);
});
</script>
<script>
    $("i").hover(function () {
    $('.icon-star').popover('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think u have to give different id for your <i> if u want them individually on hover

Comment: Why are you asking a [tag:javascript]/[tag:jquery] question under a [tag:php] tag..? **Edited to include accurate tags.** Oh, and JavaScript works client-side; post your rendered HTML ('view source'), not the PHP that generates the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what library the "popover" function belongs to, I'd say you need to change your javascript up a bit. The $("i").hover(...) code is going to make your popover happen on all "i" elements.

Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.icon-star').popover('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: all id's must be unique yes. i need the same popover for each new item though, so the same id. That answer jnunn will still give me the same problem, I will just be using classes instead of ids, the popovers will still all show at once because im using the same class. And, admittedly, this is my first time on stackoverflow and there was some php included in the code so that was why i included it as a tag. Anyway, I solved it, I just used the $this keyword instead of '.icon-star' @jnunn